# Show similarity of block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that the following block matrices

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} AB & \mathrm O_{m \times n}\\B & \mathrm O_{n \times n}\end{bmatrix} \qquad \qquad
Q = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm O_{m \times m} & \mathrm O_{m \times n}\\B&BA\end{bmatrix}$$

where $A$ is an $m\times n$ and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, are similar.

Comment: But same eigenvalues does not guarantee similarity. Example: $$\begin {bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\begin {bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ah, you are right. Sorry.

Comment: Here is an answer in this site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427703/prove-this-block-matrices-are-similar?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} 1_m & -A \\ 0 & 1_n\end{array}\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} AB & 0 \\ B & 0\end{array}\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} 1_m & A \\ 0 & 1_n\end{array}\right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} 0 & 0 \\ B & BA\end{array}\right]
$$

It may be a little more illuminating to view the situation this way:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} 1_m & A \\ 0 & 1_n\end{array}\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} 0 & 0 \\ B & 0\end{array}\right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} AB & 0 \\ B & 0\end{array}\right]
$$

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} 0 & 0 \\ B & 0\end{array}\right] 
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} 1_m & A \\ 0 & 1_n\end{array}\right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{cr} 0 & 0 \\ B & BA\end{array}\right]
$$